# Eclipse RCP product export: Cannot satisfy slf4j dependency

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am building existing RCP application against this target platform:

[image]

The PDE build worked fine just few weeks ago and then something happened, presumably Eclipse updated itself? or something like this.. Now I am getting this dependency error which makes no sense because by the look of it the required plugin and exported package is present in the target platform. If I disable p2 "Generate p2 repository" in the export dialog, the build works fine.

```
Property "p2.director.log" has not been set
[p2.director] Installing com.myclient.product 5.2.0.
[p2.director] Installation failed.
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director]   Software being installed: logFaces 5.2.0 (com.myclient.product 5.2.0)
[p2.director]   Missing requirement: Apache HttpClient 5.1.2.v20211217-1500 (org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5 5.1.2.v20211217-1500) requires 'java.package; org.slf4j [1.7.25,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
[p2.director]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director]       From: logFaces 5.2.0 (com.myclient.product 5.2.0)
[p2.director]       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.6.1300.v20220223-1131,1.6.1300.v20220223-1131]
[p2.director]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director]       From: ECF Apache Httpclient 5 FileTransfer Provider 1.1.600.v20220215-0126 (org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient5.feature.feature.group 1.1.600.v20220215-0126)
[p2.director]       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5 [5.1.2.v20211217-1500,5.1.2.v20211217-1500]
[p2.director]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director]       From: Equinox p2, headless functionalities 1.6.1300.v20220223-1131 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.6.1300.v20220223-1131)
[p2.director]       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient5.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,2.0.0)
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director] Software being installed: logFaces 5.2.0 (com.myclient.product 5.2.0)
[p2.director] Missing requirement: Apache HttpClient 5.1.2.v20211217-1500 (org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5 5.1.2.v20211217-1500) requires 'java.package; org.slf4j [1.7.25,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
[p2.director] Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director] Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director] Cannot satisfy dependency:
A problem occured while invoking the director.
runDirector:  duration 0 seconds
```

I would appreciate any help from the community on this one, thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that PDE RCP export is no longer maintained, [tag:tycho] is the only supported build mechanism. However tycho also uses p2 director so may not make a difference here.

Comment: What greg-449 says. The outdated 2022-03 release update site contains org.slf4j.api 1.7.30.v20200204-2150 containing the missing org.slf4j package (`... requires 'java.package; org.slf4j [1.7.25,2.0.0)' but it could not be found`). To find missing stuff, the [_Repository Explorer_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph_Repository_Explorer) view which is part of [_Oomph Targlets_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph_Targlets) is quite helpful. Better use [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest) instead of the outdated 2022-03 update site.

Comment: @howlger thank you for the answer, I will try the "latest". Do you think there is a way to fix current target without making another one from "latest" builds? The problem I am having is that updates always break something. I thought the idea of the Target platform was to avoid frequent changes and always build against one tested well known target as we don't really need any updates being released continuously. In my case this specific target platform was working and we released many updates of our product. Then something changed and we now have slf4j issues. That is without changing the target

Comment: Maybe in the _Content_ tab, org.slf4j.api is not checked. In the update site of the 2022-03 release there should be more than 505 plugins. So, in the _Locations_ tab, maybe you have to hit _Reload_ first. Tycho makes everything much easier. I wasted a lot of time sticking to PDE Build for far too long.

Comment: org.slf4j.api (1.7.30.v20200204-2150) is listed as part of this target platform and it exports the package needed. Reloading didn't do anything.. Tycho is not an option for us because it will require to change the entire project structure. It's probably good for new projects, won't work for existing apps. Thanks anyway! @howlger

Comment: Tycho does not require to change the project structure, but it requires a feature based product, not a plugin based product. If you have a plugin based product, make sure org.slf4j.api is added (if I remember correctly, PDE Build requires transitive dependencies to be added explicitly). Tycho would make it much easier, see for example [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized) requiring only five files: `pom.xml`, `.mvn/extensions.xml`, a feature based product plus a `category.xml` file (only required if you want to create an update site) and a target platform definition file.

Comment: @howlger tycho does not requires a feature based product. I'm the author of [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox) that builds with tycho and JMSToolBox is a plugin based product

Comment: @titou10 Thanks a lot, and also thanks for the link to JMSToolBox proving that I was wrong. Does this mean that the only limitation of a plugin-based product is that you cannot upgrade an existing installation via an update site (no _Help > Check for Updates_)?

Comment: I have ended up upgrading the Eclipse to 4.26 and re-creating the target platform from the scratch. It eventually resolved all the dependency issues.